# How to close a Windows Phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

In WP7 and WP8 I just needed to clear the backstack in a page, then press Back button and the app is closed. In WP8.1 I do Frame.BackStack.Clear(), press Back and the app just minimizes.. How to kill it with Back button?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add, in your main page definition:

```
Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
```

Then

```
private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Handled && Frame.CurrentSourcePageType.FullName == "YourApp.MainPage")
        Application.Current.Exit();
}
```

**Warning:** As others said, you should not use this and let the system handle the app closure. For example, if you use the Application Insights, I found that they are not sent to Azure when in Release mode

Comment: I don't think he will really need the `if` statement. If `e.Handled` was already handled it probably wont bubble to the `HardwareButtons_BackPressed` I guess.

Comment: @V.G. totally agree with "Everything is different from 7,8", but in the matter or "sh*t" I would put it beside "7, 8" rather then "8.1" (implying WP8.1 _WinRT_) :)

Comment: Why to check page type? simply checking  Frame.CanGoBack() will be more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

I think the above has been depreceated.  Exit is now an event.

Try

Application.Current.Terminate();

Comment: Where did you find Terminate? I see just [Exit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.exit(v=win.10).aspx)

Comment: Are you working in Windows Phone 8.0 ?  Or are you coding in 7.1.

Comment: I am using WP 8.1 RT and question was also point to this version.

Comment: Not sure man.  Do you see that method or something similar?  If Exit is just there and is a method and not an event, just try calling that.  SMH.  Microsoft is always changing things...

Answer (score 3):

you can simply create a button by using XAML and then add this code into your Main page xaml.cs

> Application.Current.Exit();

Answer (score 2):

MSDN recommends to not close apps in Windows 8.1:

> We recommend that apps not close themselves programmatically unless
>   absolutely necessary. For example, if an app detects a memory leak, it
>   can close itself to ensure the security of the user's personal data.
>   *When you close an app programmatically, the system treats this as an
>   app crash*.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx#close